# XSLT Spilt Issue

Tags: xslt

My Orginal XML Is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testing>
    <MajorEvent>
        <Originator>xxxx/Originator>
        <Version>V1</Version>
    </MajorEvent>
    <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00" >
        <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
        <ItemName>F7000533</ItemName>
        <Lang>
            <Languages>Language1|Language2</Languages>
        </Lang>
        <EventID>4333</EventID>
    </Event>
</testing>
```

I want to Produce events depending on Languages and audioname. Eg in this there are 3 events So the out put will be

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <testing>
            <MajorEvent>
                <Originator>xxxx/Originator>
                <Version>V1</Version>
            </MajorEvent>
            <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00" >
                <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
                <ItemName>F7000533</ItemName>
                <Lang>
                    <Languages>Language1|Language2</Languages>
                </Lang>
                <EventID>4333</EventID>
            </Event>
 <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00">
    <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
    <ItemName>F7000533-AT1</ItemName>
    <EventID>4333</EventID>
  </Event>
            <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00" >
                <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
                <ItemName>F7000533-Language1</ItemName>
                <Lang>
                    <Languages>Language1|Language2</Languages>
                </Lang>
                <EventID>4333</EventID>
            </Event>
            <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00" >
                <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
                <ItemName>F7000533-Language2</ItemName>
                <Lang>
                    <Languages>Language1|Language2</Languages>
                </Lang>
                <EventID>4333</EventID>
            </Event>
        </testing>
```

I have written the xslt.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/testing">
        <xsl:element name="testing">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="MajorEvent" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Event" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="MajorEvent">
        <xsl:element name="MajorEvent">
            <xsl:copy-of select="Originator" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="Version" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Event">
        <xsl:element name="Event">
            <xsl:attribute name="Date">
                              <xsl:value-of select="@Date" />
                         </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="AudioName" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="ItemName" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="EventID" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:for-each select="AudioName">
            <xsl:element name="Event">
                <xsl:attribute name="Date">
                              <xsl:value-of select="../@Date" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:variable name="item_name" select="../ItemName" />
                <xsl:variable name="audio" select="../AudioName" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="../AudioName" />
                <xsl:element name="ItemName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($item_name,'-',$audio)" />
                </xsl:element>


                <xsl:copy-of select="../EventID" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:variable name="SplitLanguage">
            <xsl:call-template name="SplitLanguage">
                <xsl:with-param name="Languages" select="Lang/Languages" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($SplitLanguage)/*">
            <xsl:element name="Event">
                <xsl:attribute name="Date">
                              <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:variable name="item_name" select="../ItemName" />
                <xsl:variable name="lang" select="." />
                <xsl:element name="ItemName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($item_name,'-',$lang)" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="SplitLanguage">
        <xsl:param name="Languages" select="." />
        <xsl:if test="string-length($Languages) >0">
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($Languages, ','), ',')" />
            </item>

            <xsl:call-template name="SplitLanguage">
                <xsl:with-param name="Languages"
                    select="substring-after($Languages, ',')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting this result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testing>
  <MajorEvent>
    <Originator>xxxx</Originator>
    <Version>V1</Version>
  </MajorEvent>
  <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00">
    <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
    <ItemName>F7000533</ItemName>
    <EventID>4333</EventID>
  </Event>
  <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00">
    <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
    <ItemName>F7000533-AT1</ItemName>
    <EventID>4333</EventID>
  </Event>
  <Event Date="">
    <ItemName>-Language1</ItemName>
  </Event>
  <Event Date="">
    <ItemName>-Language2</ItemName>
  </Event>
</testing>
```

Does anybody know what am i doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need exslt here, also you seem to be splitting on "," rather than "|"

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<x>
<xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="testing/Event"/>
</x>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Event">
 <Event Date="{@Date}">
  <xsl:copy-of select="AudioName|ItemName|EventID"/>
  </Event>
  <xsl:call-template name="splitlang">
  <xsl:with-param name="l" select="concat(Lang/Languages,'|')"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="splitlang">
<xsl:param name="l"/>
   <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$l">
 <Event Date="{@Date}">
  <xsl:copy-of select="AudioName"/>
  <ItemName>
   <xsl:value-of select="ItemName"/>
   <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($l,'|')"/>
  </ItemName>
  <xsl:copy-of select="Lang|EventID"/>
  </Event>
  <xsl:call-template name="splitlang">
   <xsl:with-param name="l" select="substring-after($l,'|')"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
<x>
   <testing>
      <MajorEvent>
         <Originator>xxxx</Originator>
         <Version>V1</Version>
      </MajorEvent>
      <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00">
         <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
         <ItemName>F7000533</ItemName>
         <Lang>
            <Languages>Language1|Language2</Languages>
         </Lang>
         <EventID>4333</EventID>
      </Event>
   </testing>
   <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00">
      <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
      <ItemName>F7000533</ItemName>
      <EventID>4333</EventID>
   </Event>
   <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00">
      <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
      <ItemName>F7000533-Language1</ItemName>
      <Lang>
         <Languages>Language1|Language2</Languages>
      </Lang>
      <EventID>4333</EventID>
   </Event>
   <Event Date="26-03-11_04:00:00:00">
      <AudioName>AT1</AudioName>
      <ItemName>F7000533-Language2</ItemName>
      <Lang>
         <Languages>Language1|Language2</Languages>
      </Lang>
      <EventID>4333</EventID>
   </Event>
</x>
```

Comment: Thanks...Was confused with template call.